# ViewController Unwind Segue Issue

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiviewcontroller, uistoryboardsegue

Let's say I have three ViewControllers. I'm segueing from VC 1 to VC 2 and from VC 2 to 3. Then I added an Unwind Segue in VC 1, so I can unwind directly from VC 3 to VC 1. The problem now is that I used the animation "cross dissolve" and VC 2 pops up for a second which is pretty ugly.

After reading some posts I think it's because VC 2 is on the ViewController stack when I call the unwind segue.
Can I delete VC 2 from the stack or is there another solution to this problem?

Every segue is a modal segue and every VC is just a normal UIViewController.

Thanks

Comment: You can do show detail segue from VC2 to VC3, this way VC2 is replaced by VC3 on top of VC1.

Comment: But I don't have any navigationcontroller. Is that a problem?

Comment: No I guess that won't be any problem.

Comment: I tried everything with a navigation controller and it works like a charm. So basicly I need to know when I should use a navigationcontroller with push segue and when to use no navigation controller and just modal segues. It's a bit confusing. @vivektakrani

Comment: Sorry for replying late. check out this link http://stackoverflow.com/a/14977304